# How to put a *.cfg file to the same directory as the *.apk file?

Tags: android, filesystems

I am really new to android devices, we have got an app that needs to read a ***.cfg** file from the same place as the apk. So the question is:

1) When i attach my mobile-phone to the computer, can i put it from the explorer? If yes, how?

2) Is there a mechanism in Android, that looks for some kind of **include directories**
 when opening a Program?

It would be great if you could give me a hint.

Comment: "that needs to read a *.cfg file from the same place as the apk" -- what does this mean? Where do you think the APK is, such that you need another file in "the same place"?

Comment: that the software expects a cfg file, it is a constraint (from the developer) but he is not available atm

Comment: Then "the software" needs to be adapted to work on Android, as you cannot write to the location where the APK is, and most developers don't even know or care where the APK is.

Comment: The software is supposed to work on android, i got it from a scientific workers, as they are atm not available, i am going through the wiki, they demand that the config file is at the root or same place as the apk file.. thats the question...but i will check that tomorrow, what quinnjn said and maybe buy your book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to drop the `*.cfg` files into the `assets/` folder. Then the app will have access to those raw `*.cfg` files during runtime.

[From Managing Projects](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html)

> assets/
>
> This is empty. You can use it to store raw asset files. Files that you
>   save here are compiled into an .apk file as-is, and the original
>   filename is preserved. You can navigate this directory in the same way
>   as a typical file system using URIs and read files as a stream of
>   bytes using the [AssetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html). For example, this is a good location for
>   textures and game data.